# Parcel Copied Application Won't Build

Tags: reactjs, parcel

I'm working on a project for a course. Part of that course is to copy and modify another project I built into a new folder. However, once the project has been copied and I've run 'npm i' the project fails to build on the first line of my class:

```
2 | 
3 | class Auth {
> 4 |   loggedIn = false;
  |              ^
5 | 
6 |   signup = () => {
7 |     // TODO
```

You can see that the es6 class isn't being compiled properly. This is the exact code working in a separate directory. I currently have it running without an issue as I type this.

Edit: Here are my dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you configure babel to have e.g. the [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2) preset so you can use [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties).

Comment: Thanks @Tholle I will try that. That doesn't make sense though. How is it building in one folder without that preset and not in my new folder? I'll update my question with my package.json.

Comment: Good question. I'm not entirely sure what's going on.

Comment: I have added the dependency as you suggested: "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1"
Still getting the same error. I suppose I can try adding a .babelrc?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was my .babelrc file was not copied over when I used "cp -r PATHFROM PATHTO". I had forgotten the project even had that file.

Here's what I was missing:

```
{
"presets": [
  "env", "react"
],
"plugins": [
  "transform-class-properties"
]
}
```

I'm using a mac and apparently, files that begin with a dot are ignored.

Hope this helps someone.